# Input disappear on mobile

Tags: javascript, reactjs, input, mobile

I have built a message app using React, TS and Firebase.
Locally all is fine (on desktop and mobile view), but once deployed, on mobile there is an issue:
The message input  ("sendMessage" component) is not visible until a user is selected. As a result once a user is selected the sendMessage appears and thus it "pushes" all the other components up. In the end the `navbar` gets out of sight because of this.

You can see on the screenshots 1st how it appears locally (all fine), 2nd how it appears on mobile once deployed before a user is selected and then after user is selected.

Any idea how to fix this? Thanks

[repository](https://github.com/jisokoo/TS-React-Chat)

[live version](https://ts-react-chat.web.app/)

[image: [screenshot 1]]

[image: [screensot 2]]

[image: [screenshot]]

I have tried several things to "force" it to appear like `visibility: visible`, `shrink: 0`, etc... but nothing seems to work.

I also know I could assign a convo by default to appear but what about first time user who don't have any convo yet?

Comment: This is probably not a css issue, but rather some logical bug in your react code. Have you tried debugging that?

Comment: @UmbQbify Well it works really well on Desktop and even when I use inspect to display mobile view. It only happens on mobile. My guess was there is a "default" behavior on mobile that hides input that aren't in use but I cannot find anything about this.

Comment: @aubarb no there isn't such s thing; can you check if you have different `@media` styles for mobile devices? Otherwise from experience, the DevTools responsive options is sometimes not how it looks like when trying on a real phone.

Comment: I tried on my iPhone and i knew that would be the case - your app doesn't consider the Toolbar; when I hid the Toolbar the input is there.

Comment: @Aleksandar thanks for your reply!
But then if it is the toolbar that's hidding why does it go up when I select a convo? even if there is still the toolbar?
Amd do you have an idea how I can fix that?

Comment: @aubarb hey so I visited your `App.scss` and styling being styling (*and not my cup of tea* xD) - I may only be 100% sure if I test it on a minimal code sample..; I'd still go with suggesting you to change the `body` element's `overflow` into `auto`?

Comment: @Aleksandar thanks a lot for your help! Quite right, it doesn't fix the height problem to adapt to the mobile but does enable user to scroll and see top or bottom, nice improvement thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

From what I saw on mobile the input is visible it's just that the height of the app is bigger than the screen (check the image attached). It's difficult to say what exactly to change but I would try to modify the height from this code:

```
.home .chat .messages {
    background-color: rgba(147,178,235,.3);
    height: calc(100% - 110px);
    overflow-y: scroll;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

Maybe try to add `display: flex` on `.home .chat` and a `flex-grow: 1` on `.home .chat .messages` without the `height` property.

[image: Image from my screen]

Comment: Indeed I think you are right about the height.
I managed to changed that with a mix of what you said but also had to put .app height and change some other bloc height. Now the input is showing but the navbar is hidden... I really don't understand.